# Under what conditions does Malthael drop legendary pieces or plans?

Tags: diablo-iii

After first beating Malthael in Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls, I received 3 legendary drops.

1. [Reaper's Wraps](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/reapers-wraps)
2. [Reaper's Fear](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/reapers-fear)
3. A legendary pair of boots that dropped probably because I was lucky.

While I'm fairly certain that the boots were a random drop, I don't think I could get as lucky to get Reaper's Wraps and Fear without there being a method to their drops.

Are all of these drops random? Do you always get the crafting material with the plan? I think that the Reapers items only drop upon killing Malthael, but I killed him again and I did not get any legendaries.

How can I get more of these legendary drops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fear is random, some people need to farm him over and over to get 1
When you first kill him you get a guaranteed legendary, thus the boots. Reset your quests and you'll get another.
The plan all my friends got on their first kill as well so not sure.

Answer (score 2):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#Crafting). Malthael will always drop the plan at level 60+, as long as the player does not already have the plan.

The material remains a random drop from Malthael.

> Malthael will now always drop the plan for Reapers' Wraps when killed
>   at level 60 or higher if the player does not have the recipe, instead
>   of only on the first kill