# What are the Malthael only legendaries?

Tags: diablo-iii

After first beating Malthael in Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls, I received 3 legendary drops.

1. [Reaper's Wraps](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/reapers-wraps)
2. [Reaper's Fear](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/reapers-fear)
3. A legendary pair of boots that dropped probably because I was lucky.

After reading some on the wiki page for the Reapers' items, it seems that they only drop upon killing Malthael.

Are there other legendaries that are only dropped by defeating Malthael?

If so, what are the other legendaries that are only dropped by Malthael?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Under what conditions does Malthael drop legendary pieces or plans?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161771/under-what-conditions-does-malthael-drop-legendary-pieces-or-plans)

Comment: @user1032613 Having the same answer does not make it the same question.

Comment: I didn't know these would have the same answer when I asked them, and they are definitely different questions. I thought there might be 12 different Malthael-only legendaries - seems that I was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malthael's "reserved" legendaries are Reaper's Wraps (Plan) and Reaper's Fear (crafting material). The Plan is a guaranteed drop the first time you kill Malthael, you got lucky to get the Reaper's Fear with it. I killed him twice with no such luck. The pair of boots is part of the First-kill-reward as well. I got a helm and the Plan